# Mistakenly clicked "Leave Closed" while reviewing "Reopen Votes" question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I'm reviewing (Reopen Votes) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18447577) and mistakenly clicked on Leave Closed button but I actually wants to Reopen the question.

However, what should I do now to Reopen it?

Comment: Reopen vote on the question outside of the queue.

Comment: I'm not required to give a reason if I feel the explanation in the tooltip is sufficient.

Comment: If you're particularly worried that you've done harm by knocking a reopen-worthy question out of the queue, you could always drop into [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) and leave a `reopen-pls` request.

Comment: @MarkAmery Its helpful.

Comment: That question should stay closed, anyway. It's a duplicate

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto then just flag that question which is duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can navigate to your [reopen queue history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history), identify the question, click on it, and manually cast a reopen vote.

That way, while it will have a vote to leave closed in the queue, it will also have an extra reopen vote. The comment by Makyen has more details on how leave closed votes and reopen votes work.

Comment: As I understand it, it's inaccurate to say it's got "one vote in both directions from you". My understanding is, the "Leave Closed" only counts within the close-vote-review-queue and wrt. does the question stay in the queue, or get kicked out of the queue. The vote to reopen (from within the queue, or not) is an actual reopen vote. Clicks on "Leave Closed" don't counter/offset reopen votes. For reopening, what counts is getting enough total reopen votes prior to them aging away.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the comment. I tried to edit my question to something a little more refined. Feel free to edit it, if you feel the exacts are relevant. I can make it a community wiki if you want to contribute.